# Maintaining a sorted list of numbers in multiset and the cumulative sums in another

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, containers, multiset

I have an application in which integers are presented in no particular order. The integers presented can be repeat values. I have to maintain them in a sorted fashion. Each time a new entry is presented, it needs to be placed in the appropriate position so that the sorted order is maintained.

[`std::multiset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/insert/) seems to be one suggested solution with the best time, `O(log n)`, for insertion.

Now, in addition to this sorted multiset, I have to maintain the cumulative sums in another container.

That is, if the sorted entries are:

1, 5, 7, 9 (in indices 0, 1, 2 and 3)

the cumulative sum container would be:

1, 6, 13, 22 (in indices 0, 1, 2 and 3)

I am having trouble figuring out how to use the `std::multiset` iterator that is returned after each `insert(int)` operation into the multiset in order to update the cumulative sum container. Note that the cumulative sum will only affect in those entries and indices that have to be moved because of the insert operation.

That is, if to the above list, `insert(8)` has to be performed, the updated containers would be:

Sorted entries:

1, 5, 7, 8, 9 (in indices 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4)

Cumulative sum:

1, 6, 13, 21, 30 (in indices 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. Note that only entries in indices 3 and 4 are affected.)

At present, the only way I have been able to implement this is by using two arrays, one for the array of values and one for the cumulative sum. A working code that implements this is presented below:

```
#include <iostream>


int *arr = new int[100];//Array to maintain sorted list
int *cum_arr = new int[100];//Array to maintain cumulative sum

void insert_into_position(int val, int &last_valid_index_after_insertion) {
    //Inserts val into arr such that after insertion
    //arr[] has entries in ascending order.

    int postoadd = last_valid_index_after_insertion;
    //index in array at which to insert val
    //initially set to last_valid_index_after_insertion

    //Search from end of array until you find the right
    //position at which to insert val
    for (int ind = last_valid_index_after_insertion - 1; ind >= 0; ind--) {
        if (arr[ind] > val) {
            postoadd--;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    //Move everything from and including postoadd one position to the right.
    //Update the cumulative sum array as you go
    for (int ind = last_valid_index_after_insertion - 1; ind >= postoadd; ind--) {
        arr[ind + 1] = arr[ind];
        cum_arr[ind + 1] = cum_arr[ind] + val;
    }

    //Update entry in index postoadd
    arr[postoadd] = val;
    if (postoadd > 0)
        cum_arr[postoadd] = cum_arr[postoadd - 1] + val;
    else
        cum_arr[0] = val;
    last_valid_index_after_insertion++;
}

int main(void)
{
    int length = 0;
    insert_into_position(1, length);
    insert_into_position(5, length);
    insert_into_position(7, length);
    insert_into_position(9, length);

    printf("\nPrint sorted array\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\nPrint Cumulative sum array\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%d ", cum_arr[i]);

    insert_into_position(8, length);

    printf("\nPrint sorted array\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\nPrint Cumulative sum array\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%d ", cum_arr[i]);

    getchar();
}
```

As can be seen from this code, to calculate the cumulative sum, the integer array index, `postoadd` can be used until the end of the array is reached.

Is there any combination of containers that can perform better/more efficiently than the two integer arrays?

The return type of a `std::multiset.insert(int)` operation is an iterator that points to the inserted entry. Can this iterator be used to update another container that stores the cumulative sum?

Comment: So you allow duplicate values, e.g. `1, 5, 7, 9, 9` and `1, 6, 13, 22, 31`, right?

Comment: instead of maintaining 2 separate multisets - use one multiset of pairs. first of each pair will be value, second - cumulating sum. iterator returned by insert will be used to - take second of the prev and calculate cumulative sum of inserted entry, and then loop from iter+1 till end() to update second of all the following entries

Comment: @gsamaras yes, duplicates are allowed

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky I think that would indeed work. Is there a way to insert and instruct multiset to sort based on the first of the pair?

Comment: @Tryer yes, it is a multimap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`std::multimap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/multimap/), which keeps the keys sorted, and allows for duplicate keys.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main ()
{
  std::multimap<int,int> mymultimap = { {1, 1}, {5, 6}, {7, 13}, {9, 22} };
  std::multimap<int,int>::iterator it;

  it = mymultimap.insert (std::pair<char,int>(8, 8));

  if(mymultimap.size() > 1) {
    it->second = std::prev(it)->second + it->second;
    ++it;
    while(it!=mymultimap.end()) {
      it->second = std::prev(it)->second + it->first;
      ++it;
    }
  }

  // showing contents:
  std::cout << "mymultimap contains:\n";
  for (it=mymultimap.begin(); it!=mymultimap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << (*it).first << " => " << (*it).second << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
mymultimap contains:
1 => 1
5 => 6
7 => 13
8 => 21
9 => 30
```

---

PS: Another approach would be to use `std::multiset` where every element would be `std::pair`, where the first would be the number, and the second the cumulative sum.

Comment: the operation within while( it!= mymultimap.end()){ } of ++it, is each increment going to be in constant time? That is, the next time it->first or it->second is needed, is the access immediate? Thanks for the full working code.

Comment: separately - case should be handled when it returned by insert is begin(). prev() on it will cause undefined behavior

Comment: @Tryer yes constant time. That depends on whether or not they are present in data cache (if that's what you are asking).

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky thanks, code updated! Thank you for the upvote too!

Comment: @gsamaras My question is rather that when it->first is referenced within the while loop, it is immediate access and not that it starts from the beginning or end or somewhere else and has to "navigate" to it.

Comment: Oh yeah @Tryer, you have the iterator to it, thus you index it immediately.

Comment: Another note - if you remember your value added (8) - you can just update cumulative sums like `it->second += value;`

Comment: @gsamaras your current solution does not seem correct. For, if I insert (-1, -1), the returned iterator will be the beginning and your code will not do anything further. While it should actually be doing some updations.

Comment: @Tryer that should happen if the map is empty and you insert only one element. Is this the case? If not, please explain.

Comment: There are two special cases to take care of. One is when the first entry is made into the map, (x,x). Then, if a new lowest key is input (y,y), where y < x for all x keys already existing in the multimap. Here, insert will return an iterator pointing to the beginning. Yet, the subsequent cumulative updates have to happen.

Comment: As indicated by Tryer, your code does not properly handle inserting an item at the beginning. Also, I think could be a bit simpler...